# HTML text binding in view(with trustAsHtml) from JSON, having ng-Class does not evaluate properly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-class

I'm having a header with two solid div's one below the other. When we scroll the page, I've included animation in my controller to hide the bottom div. This top DIV has a couple of changes too when we scroll down the page. I'm controlling that with `smallHeader.floatItRight` and `smallHeader.floatItLeft` in ng-Class. As you can see from the ss_header.html(directive template) the ordinary div which has the class `smallHeader.floatItRight`works perfectly while the 'smallHeader.floatItRight' in ng-Class binding from JSON file does not work properly. Any ideas or thoughts on this? Thanks in advance.

JSON File has this key and corresponding value:

```
"headerHtmlContent":"<p class=\"coupons-text\" data-ng-class=\"smallHeader.floatItRight\">{{clippedCoupons}} Coupons Clipped | Your Savings:</p><p class=\"printable-text\">Printable | <a href=\"#\" class=\"disable-text\" data-ng-class=\"smallHeader.floatItLeft\">Direct2Card</a></p></div>",
```

Main HTML having the directive:

```
 <ss-header styles="smallHeader" show="showHeader" header="headerHTML"></ss-header>
```

Directive.js:

```
myApp.directive("ssHeader", ['$compile', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: "E", //directive for element only 
    //replace: true, //replace the custom tag
    scope:{
        show:'=show',
        headerHTML: '=header',
        smallHeader: '=styles'
    }, 
    templateUrl: 'common/header/ss_header.html',
  }
}]);
```

Directive HTML template:

```
<!--BINDING FROM JSON-->
    <header data-ng-show="show" class="ss-header" data-ng-bind-html="headerHTML|convertAsHtml">
    </header>
<!--NORMAL DIV WHERE NG-CLASS WORKS-->
    <div data-ng-class="smallHeader.floatItRight">Sample DIV to show smallHeader.floatItRight works!!</div>
```

Controller:

```
angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
            var scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
            if(scrollPos > previousTop){
               $scope.fadeAnimation = true;
               $scope.smallHeader = {
                    floatItRight: "fright",
                    floatItLeft: "fleft"
               }
            }
            else
                $scope.fadeAnimation = false;
            previousTop = scrollPos;
            $scope.$apply();        
        });

var generalServ = new fetchServiceData($service.api.SS_RESP);

    generalServ.save().$promise.then(function(response){

        $scope.headerHTML = $interpolate(response.en_US.siteLayout.headerHtmlContent)($scope);

    },function(err){
        console.log('error in fetching service data')
    });
```

styles.css

```
.fleft{float:left;}
.fright{float:right;}

.coupons-text.fright{float:right;}
.disable-text.fleft{float:left;}
```

Comment: I don't see any place where JSON content "headerHtmlContent" is used in you sample code. Is relevant here?

Comment: @shershen, yes! I've added some content to my controller. I'm getting 'headerHtmlContent' from a service and binding that to a scope variable $scope.headerHTML which binds to the directive template. Let me know if you need any more clarification on this.

Comment: First, check if the  generalServ.save() promise is resolved successfully ($scope.headerHTML is defined ) by the moment you start scrolling? do you get any actual error in your code?

Comment: I don't get any errors in my console. My promise is resolved and my headerHTML also comes perfectly.

Comment: The issue I guess, is - ng-Class that comes from JSON. In developer tools, when I see the HTML, it comes like this: <p class="coupons-text" data-ng-class="smallHeader.floatItRight">Coupons Clipped | Your Savings: </p>. When I scroll the page, the class **fright** should have got added. But it's not. Whereas the ordinary <div> which is **not** binding from JSON adds the class 'fright'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-bind-html` will not work because you got directives and interpolation in your html. Angulars `ngBindHtml` directive is used for plain html only. In your `ssHeader` directive you need to compile the header string. Something like so will do the trick.

```js
angular.module('MyApp', [])
  .controller('MyController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.showHeader = true;
      $scope.smallHeader = {
        'fleft': false,
        'fright': false,
      };
      $scope.headerHTML = "<p class=\"coupons-text\" data-ng-class=\"styles\">{{clippedCoupons}} Coupons Clipped | Your Savings:</p><p class=\"printable-text\">Printable | <a href=\"#\" class=\"disable-text\" data-ng-class=\"styles\">Direct2Card</a></p></div>";
    }
  ])
  .directive("ssHeader", ['$compile', '$parse',
    function($compile, $parse) {
      return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
          show: '=',
          header: '=',
          styles: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'common/header/ss_header.html',
        compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {

          return function postLink(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            var headerElement = element.find('header');
            scope.$watch(attrs.header, function(html) {
              headerElement.html(html);
              $compile(headerElement.contents())(scope);
            });
            headerElement.html(scope.header);
            $compile(headerElement.contents())(scope);
          };
        }
      }
    }
  ]);
```

```css
.fleft {
  float: left;
}
.fright {
  float: right;
}
.coupons-text.fright {
  float: right;
}
.disable-text.fleft {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
  <label>float right <input type="checkbox" ng-model="smallHeader.fright" /></label>
  <label>float left <input type="checkbox" ng-model="smallHeader.fleft" /></label>
  
  <ss-header styles="smallHeader" show="showHeader" header="headerHTML"></ss-header>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="common/header/ss_header.html">
    <div>
      <header data-ng-show="show" class="ss-header">
      </header>
      <!--NORMAL DIV WHERE NG-CLASS WORKS-->
      <div data-ng-class="styles">Sample DIV to show smallHeader.floatItRight works!!</div>
    </div>
  </script>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**:
I will try to explain the use of the compile function & `$compile` service if I can. Before I go any further I would like to state that in the directive written in the snippet above **we do not actually make use of the compile method**, we could have used the link method directly.

#### *use $compile service when:*

In general we use the $compile service to compile an html fragment that contains directives and angular stuff against a given scope to make it "**alive**". Then we place the compiled html where we need it to be. In this case we compile the html fragment against the host directive scope which is only available in the link method (see the postLink function) then we put it inside the header element using jQLite.

#### *use compile method when:*

The compile method is preferred over link method whenever we need to manipulate the directive's template dynamically before any wiring up happens. Before it becomes "alive". An example of this would be if we wanted to change the default template depending on a `urlTemplate` directive attribute `<my-directive template-url="/apath/my-cutom-template.html">`

Comment: is it possible for you to give comments in the compile function,  to explain the code in it so that, it benefits others also please?